# isLoggedIn value from authService is always true

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4

Im using `BehaviorSubject` to check if the user logged in and I do not fully understand how this approach works. I did `unsubscription` from all Observers but the value still true. I have following directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appShowIfLoggedIn]'
})
export class ShowIfLoggedInDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input('appShowIfLoggedIn') isLoggedIn: boolean;
    private unsubscribe$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.authService
            .isLoggedIn()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
                if (isAuthenticated && this.isLoggedIn) {
                    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
                } else {
                    this.viewContainer.clear();
                }
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unsubscribe$.next();
        this.unsubscribe$.complete();
    }
}
```

And passing this attribute to the HTML element should hide it if the user not logged in. This directive uses following AuthService:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    authSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());
    userRoles: BehaviorSubject<UserRoles> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private storage: Storage) {}

    register(user: CreateUser): Observable<RegistrationResponse> {
        return this.httpClient
            .post<RegistrationResponse>(`${API_ENDPOINTS.API_V1}auth/users/`, user)
            .pipe(
                tap(async (res: RegistrationResponse) => {
                    if (res.username) {
                        await this.storage.set('USERNAME', res.username);
                        this.authSubject.next(true);
                    }
                })
            );
    }

    login(user: Login): Observable<LoginResponse> {
        return this.httpClient
            .post(`${API_ENDPOINTS.API_V1}auth/token/login/`, user)
            .pipe(
                tap(async (res: LoginResponse) => {
                    if (res.auth_token) {
                        await this.storage.set('ACCESS_TOKEN', res.auth_token);
                        this.authSubject.next(true);
                        this.getUserRoles()
                            .pipe(takeUntil(timer(10000)))
                            .subscribe(data => {
                                this.userRoles.next({ roles: data.roles });
                            });
                    }
                })
            );
    }

    getUserRoles() {
        return this.httpClient.get(`${API_ENDPOINTS.API_V1}get-user-roles/`);
    }

    getUserRolesSubject() {
        return this.userRoles.asObservable();
    }

    hasRole(roles: string[]): boolean {
        for (const role of roles) {
            if (!this.userRoles.value || !this.userRoles.value.roles.includes(role)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    getAuthorizationToken() {
        return this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN');
    }

    async logout() {
        await this.storage.clear().then(() => {
            this.authSubject.next(false);
            this.userRoles.next(null);
        });
    }

    isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.authSubject.asObservable().pipe(share());
    }

    private hasToken(): boolean {
        if (this.storage.get('ACCESS_TOKEN')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Im passing this directive to the `fab button` in two different pages like so:

```
<div *appShowIfLoggedIn="true">
    <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
        <ion-fab-button>
            <ion-icon name="add" routerLink="/tabs/dictionary/add" routerDirection="forward"></ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab>
</div>
```

Logging in and out of the system removes this button from the home view BUT when you go to another page, where the same button with the same directive defined, its appears there(but shouldn't), and then you returns to the home page back, it is displayed again.

```
Issue description. Hide button if user logged out:
                   |    Page 1   |    Page 2   |  
 Step 1. Login     |    visible  |             |
 Step 2. Logout    | not visible |             |
 Step 3. Go to P2  |             |   visible   |
 Step 4. Go back P1|   visible   |             |
```

---

update > I've just removed it from Page 1 completely new started the app and without logging in checked if it appears on Page 2 and it is o_O. So the problem may be here. This Page 2 is lazyLoaded module.

Comment: Would it possible for you to create a Working Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue?

Comment: Yeah I'll do, otherwise its too complex